# "Microsoft.Data.Entity" dll not found in nuget

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, nuget-package, dbcontext

For one of my projects i am using asp.net mvc core and in this web application, for using EntityFramework i am not able to download 'Microsoft.Data.Entity' from nuget.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was due to ASP.Net Core framework was not installed correctly, i tried it in Visual Studio 2017 and guess what it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

you have to install 2 package using the package manager

```
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer
```

Then in your code, require it:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
```

Answer (score 0):

The package you need for EF Core is:

```
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer
```

Comment: while i try to download this package from nuget, i am getting error like : 

'Install-Package : An error occurred while retrieving package metadata for 'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyModel.1.1.1' from source '

Comment: Flaky internet connection?

Comment: facing same issue while downloading couple of more packages from nuget.